# Error when trying to use math powers in Java

Tags: java, pow

I am trying to do the equation `FinalValue = InitialDeposit * (1 + r)^t`  where `t = years` and `r = rate`, but I'am having the hardest time figuring out the proper format.

This is what I have, but it keeps throwing a conversion error in the `printf` method.

Here is my code:

```
package cs520.hw2.part1;

import java.lang.Math;

public class BankingProceduralStyle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // bankACalc;
        int bankAyears = 3;
        double bankADeposit = 5000;
        double bankARate = 0.04;

        double bankAFinalValue = bankADeposit * (1 + bankARate) * Math.pow(0.04, 3);

        System.out.printf("BankA %s CD of %.2f at 4.00% rate is worth $%.2f ", bankAyears, bankADeposit, bankAFinalValue);

     }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: `(1 + bankARate) * Math.pow(0.04, 3)` is not the correct way to implement your equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your calculation is wrong.

```
double bankAFinalValue = bankADeposit * Math.pow((1 + bankARate), bankAyears);
```

Then fix your printf statement: `4.00%` should be `4.00%%`.

Comment: `4.00%` should be `%f%%`, with `100 * bankARate` as an additional parameter ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line -

```
System.out.printf("BankA %s CD of %.2f at 4.00% rate is worth $%.2f ", bankAyears, bankADeposit, bankAFinalValue);
```

As you can see, you have written `4.00% rate`. Now this is being interpreted as `%r`. Remove the `%`, or add another `%`, and you should be good to go

Comment: Or double it: `%%` produces a literal `%` sign.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`System.out.printf("BankA %s CD of %.2f at 4.00% rate is worth $%.2f ", bankAyears, bankADeposit, bankAFinalValue);`

with

`System.out.printf("BankA %d CD of %.2f at 4.00%% rate is worth $%.2f ", bankAyears, bankADeposit, bankAFinalValue);`

**Reason**

You need to escape the '%' sign in `4.00%` without doing which you will give you a conversion exception. To escape it, you need to use an extra `%` before it.

Comment: That's not the problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I edited my answer to give further explanation. See if it addresses your concern.

Comment: I'll remove the DV because you've given code that works; but you should also explain why it's necessary to change `%s` to `%d` (even though it's not).

Answer (score -1):

Giving %% gives you the desired format.

```
import java.lang.Math;

class Ideone {

public static void main(String[] args) {

// bankACalc;
int bankAyears = 3;
double bankADeposit = 5000;
double bankARate = 0.04;

    double bankAFinalValue =bankADeposit *(1 + bankARate)*Math.pow(0.04,5);


        System.out.printf("BankA %s CD of %.2f at 4.00%% rate is worth $%.6f ", bankAyears, bankADeposit, bankAFinalValue);



     }

}
```

Ideone link of the above program
http://ideone.com/S4CjJa

Comment: If you put 5000 in the bank for 3 years and got 0.000532 out, would you be happy?